# After redirect from one controller to another controller Not able to receive User.Identity.name value in mvc. how to solve this Issue?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am able to get the `User.Identity.Name` value from Login `Controller` after redirect to Dashboard(another `Controller`) i am not able to receive the `User.Identity.Name` value (i am getting `Null` value)

below is my code:-

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SignInCallback()
    {
        var token = Request.Form["id_token"];
        var state = Request.Form["state"];
        var claims = await ValidateIdentityTokenAsync(token, state);
        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Cookies");
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(id);
        string Id = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; 
        return Redirect("/Dashboard");
    }
```

After **return Redirect("/Dashboard");** Getting `null` value in Dashbord `Controller`.

Below is my Dashborad `controller` code :-

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string Id = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: after return Redirect("/Dashboard"); i am getting null value

Comment: I got solution for this Problem.                                                                           Instead of `return Redirect("/Dashboard");`  we have to add our Redirect URL to  `Response.Redirect("/Dashboard");`
 after adding URL to Response we have return normal  `return View();`        after this i am able to receive `user.identity.name` value  in the Dashboard `controller`.